# FileVisitor not behaving as expected

Tags: java

I have been trying to use a class that implements `FileVisitor` and simply copies a directory in `preVisitDirectory`, moves the files, and deletes the directory in `postVisitDirectory. This works without any problems.

The problem occurs when I try to implement a conditional: `if(Files.list(dir).findAny().isEmpty())`

All but the shallowest subdirectories persist in the original directory. The target directory is filled out 100% correctly. No error is thrown.

If I use `skip(1)` in the stream *of the conditional*, a DirectoryNotEmptyException is thrown. *on the delete line.*Functionality is incorrect, i.e., the same as if I used the conditional without `skip`.

If I do a printout with `Files.list(dir).forEach(System.out::println);`, functionality is incorrect and the exception is thrown, again on the delete line

Another human thinks functionality was not as intended because this:

'System.out.println(dir + " : ");
Files.list(dir).forEach(System.out::println);'

Outputs:

> E:\EncrypterTest\TopSecret\NestedFolder\DoublyNestedFolder\TriplyNestedFolder:
> E:\EncrypterTest\TopSecret\NestedFolder\DoublyNestedFolder:
> E:\EncrypterTest\TopSecret\NestedFolder\DoublyNestedFolder\TriplyNestedFolder
> E:\EncrypterTest\TopSecret\NestedFolder :
> E:\EncrypterTest\TopSecret\NestedFolder\DoublyNestedFolder

Where TriplyNestedFolder is the deepest folder in the directory. Remember, TriplyNestedFolder is being deleted when the code is complete. So are the other 2 if I don't check if they are empty.

So to recap it seems like:

1. The deepest directory is being accessed first (as expected), but despite `.delete` being called on it, it still exists for the purpose of the `.delete` in it's parent directory.
2. It is deleted after code completes
3. Parent directories are all deleted as well with no exception thrown
4. Adding a conditional as shown above causes copies of all but the deepest directory to remain
5. Adding a `.skip(1)` in the files stream causes functionality from #4, but produces DirectoryNotEmptyException
6. Adding a printout causes the same functionality and exception from #5
7. Exact same behavior occurs with or without files in the directories

I'm hoping this will be something obvious to someone here, but I'm at a loss. Thanks in advance for any help. If you need any more information/code please ask.

Comment: Explaining code is usually unclear. Show code, expected results and actual results, and this question is more readable.

Comment: Tried to be as clear as possible but next time I'll copy paste a big block of code and maybe a video, since the results varied based off what I tried I assumed it would've made it less clear. Andreas seemed to understand the problem and had a solution, so I've marked it as answered.

Comment: Next time leave the irrelevant details about some person on a discord server out. Ask the question with technical details. No need for "I've spent weeks on this" or "I talked to some person who I think was more experienced". That's how SO works, so don't act all hurt about me teaching you how to behave properly here (although I shouldn't be considered as an example on how to behave properly, do as I say, not as I do).

Comment: You don't have to paste a big block of code. But you can use actual directories? You can include the code that throws the exception. There is quite a difference between what you're saying you'll include next and and your description. Such things as "All but the shallowest subdirectories persist in the original directory" can readily be made clearer by using directory names as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc of [`Files.list(Path dir)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) says:

> Return a **lazily** populated Stream, the elements of which are the entries in the directory. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> The returned stream encapsulates a `DirectoryStream`. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the **try-with-resources** construct should be used to ensure that the stream's `close` method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.
>
> [...]

This means that the returned stream keeps an open OS directory handle, which on Windows may prevent the directory from being deleted.

Correct use of `Files.list()` is:

```java
boolean isEmpty;
try (Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.list(dir)) {
    isEmpty = pathStream.findAny().isEmpty();
}
if (isEmpty) {
    // We can delete the directory here, since we've now released
    // the resources used by the stream, i.e. we've closed the handle
}
```

Comment: Well, my entire existence yesterday was trying to figure this out and you answered within about 6 seconds of me posting this thread. Tested and it works, thank you very much.